# Google Coral: Is there a limit to model size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, google-coral, edge-tpu

I was looking to use a relatively large model (~300 MB Tflite) but I'm concerned it may not be supported by Google Coral due to its size. That's where my questions come from.

- How exactly does it work? Is the model loaded into the Coral itself? Or does Google Coral act like a coprocessor where the CPU hands it tasks and it provides results?
- If it is indeed loaded, how large of a model/data can it support?

Most of the info I read implies that it can't handle much since they talk about `YOLOv4-Tiny` and `mobilenet-ssd` for example. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58610916/3979290) makes it seem like there is no size limit for Google Coral.

I did read that a [Google Coral has 8MB of SRAM](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/compiler/#parameter-data-caching), but it's used as a cache it seems.

Comment: Is your TPU tflite model of ~300 MB ?

Comment: @Manoj Yes, it is

Comment: 300 MB is too much for EdgeTPU I believe. Please read : The Edge TPU has roughly 8 MB of SRAM that can cache the model's parameter data. However, a small amount of the RAM is first reserved for the model's inference executable, so the parameter data uses whatever space remains after that. Naturally, saving the parameter data on the Edge TPU RAM enables faster inferencing speed compared to fetching the parameter data from external memory.